# Can Python iterate over a list of tuples and select only the ones that match a certain string?

Tags: python

I'm using SpaCy to perform name entity recognition on a block of text, with the end goal of assembling a simple list of people's names.

So far, I've been successful in using SpaCy to give me a list of tuples, 'corpents'; the entity's name is the first element in each tuple, and the tag is the second element.

I want to iterate over each tuple, check to see if the second element is PERSON and if it is, append the first element of that tuple to a list of strings called 'entities'.

I know this is more elementary Python, but I'm a beginner.

Comment: Add the sample data and the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: It's okay; Paul Becotte's answer below worked for me.

Comment: Please still add the sample data and the code that you have tried so far. We appreciate all efforts to show that something was genuinely attempted, even if the question was answered (that also helps avoid the question being put on hold too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
results = [x[0] for x in tuples if x[1] == "PERSON"]
```

sounds like what you want? Iterate through the list, and for each value if it passes a test, insert part of the value into a collection.

Comment: That did it.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Jack This is called a *list comprehension* if you want to study more about it.